# What are the benefits of Reflection?

Tags: c#, java, c++, .net, reflection

I especially hope to understand the principle that drives you to use it despite that it is not efficient. Correct me if what I say is not true.

Another way of looking at this question can be why should we use it and why not? Is Reflection a good way of programmation?

Thank you.

Comment: Your question suggests that reflection offers a sensible alternative in numerous situations. I think this is a misconception.

Comment: In C++, you shouldn't use it because it doesn't exist. I can't comment on the other languages, except to quote Knuth in saying that we should forget about small efficiencies, say about 97% of the time: premature optimization is the root of all evil.

Comment: @Jodrell As Mike says Reflection doesn't exist in C++ and a lot of other languages so there are alternatives. Maybe it is complex and expensive to implement.

Answer (score 3):

http://csharp.net-tutorials.com/reflection/introduction/

http://www.csharp-examples.net/reflection-examples/

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/17269/Reflection-in-C-Tutorial

http://www.codeguru.com/csharp/csharp/cs_misc/reflection/article.php/c4257

I'm not being arrogant by posting these links - I just think with a few mins of 'googling' you'll have the same explanation you're waiting for here anyway.

Answer (score 2):

## .NET Perspective

Many frameworks within the .NET framework will stop working without reflection. ASP.NET MVC is purely working on reflection.

It is powerful but the *power comes with responsibility*. Reflection is slow, so you need to be sure what you are doing.

Answer (score 1):

`Reflection` gives un enormous benefits in architecturing the software. 
For example `plug-in base systems` are *almost* unthinkable to be developed without heavy use of it.

It's very powerful (and in `.NET` very performant) feature that let's you read/write the data at runtime in dynamic and generic way.

Answer (score 0):

reflection is a good technology. But its a heavy weight thing. And dont just go about using reflection every where just beacuse you learned how to use it. Use it only where really necessary.

Hope this PPT helps you learn: 
http://www.slideshare.net/rohitvipin/reflection-power-pointpresentation-ppt